# Find the points on the curve where the tangent is vertical

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, curves

**Question.** Given $y^{2}=x^{3}+ax+b$, find the points on the curve where the tangent line is vertical.

**Attempt.** Let $f(x,y)=x^{3}-y^{2}+ax+b=0$

The tangent is vertical at points where the gradient is horizontal.

The gradient is horizontal if and only if $$\begin{cases}
-2y=0\\
3x^{2}+a\neq0\\
y^{2}=x^{3}+ax+b
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow\begin{cases}
x^{2}\neq-\frac{a}{3}\\
x^{3}+ax+b=0
\end{cases}$$

I'm not sure how to continue forward.

Comment: You're right. Your problem requires solving cubic equation $x^3+ax+b=0$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu But it depends on the values of a and b, and I don't know how to solve it

Comment: General solution of cubic equation is not very simple, but you can use ready formula for it (Cardano formula).